# Deleted my *.gwt.xml file

Tags: gwt

I deleted my *.gwt.xml file. When I recreated it my gwt app runs fine in debug mode but when i open it in production it gives me a blank screen. I believe missing an inheritance is there a way to find out which one?

Comment: Okay i found out my app works in firefox and safari but not chrome ?? any idea why?

Comment: When you say production, you mean you compile it using eclipse built in tool or you wrote your own ant?

Comment: compiling it using eclipse built in tool. But it runs in chrome in when running in debug from eclipse.

Comment: I am getting this error in the console Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file:///BLAHBLAH.html from frame with URL file:///BLAHBLAH.cache.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match. I never open this app in chrome after compiling before but i am using this app in phonegap on android which shows a blank screen i am assuming its the same error and it worked in phonegap before

Comment: If it is working in one browser but not another, it's usually because of the browser setting. Google chrome and google webtoolkit are supposed to go together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it i had

```
<module rename-to='AppName'>
```

But apparently u can't use caps it needs to be

```
<module rename-to='appname'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it compile?

If it does not, use `--logLevel DEBUG` for java compilation call (or you can set it directly in eclipse project setting) to find out which module is lost.

If it compiles, just use debug mode to track where it crashes.